# If else in Google Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I want to write a google script that will delete all the cells in column 'N' if row 'R' has the text 'Rejected'.
I have written this script but it deleting all the cells in Column 'N'. help me with my error or suggest a 
better script.

```js
function clean0() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tasks');

  for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 18).getValue();

    if (workingCell = '0') {
      activeSheet.getRange(i, 14).setValue("a");
    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (workingCell = '0')` this is *assignment*, use `==` or `===` for comparison

Answer (score 0):

As @VLAZ said, you have to use `==` or `===` instead of `=` to compare two values.

From [Comparision operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

```
console.log(1 == 1);
// expected output: true

console.log('1' == 1);
// expected output: true

console.log(1 === 1);
// expected output: true

console.log('1' === 1);
// expected output: false
```

In case of `if (workingCell = '0'`, it always returns `true` as it's an assignement, not a comparision.